# Title: How to use a function that take a record in a select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

This code is working

```
declare
    tA table of rA; --where ra is a record
    tB table of rB; --where rb is a record
    A Ta;
    B Tb;  
begin
    A    :=gettA(); -- where gettA return type is tA
    B    :=gettBFromtA(A); -- where gettB return type is tB and take an input of type tA
end;
```

But now I am in this situation:

I haven’t gettBFromtA but getrBFromRa where getrBFromRa return type is rB and take an input of type rA. And I want to get B from A.

A solution to do the same thing as in the code in the beginning would be to create an intermediary function Inter such as

```
function Inter (arg1 in ra.field1%type, ….. argn in ra.fieldn%type ) return rb
is
      a ra;
      b rb
begin
      ra.arg1 := arg1 ….. ra.argn := argn
      return getrBFromRa(a);
end;
```

and replace the penultimate line by

```
select Inter(t.arg1, … t.argn) bulk collect into B from table(A) t.
```

Is there a simpler way to do that?

In addition to that, the definition of the record will probably change. And I would like to avoid to write several time the names of the fields of my records.

I am looking for a way to use getrBFromrA directly in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simulate your problem. First, I created below objects in DB :

```
CREATE table stack59565292(
       ID number(6),
       NAME varchar2(20)
);

insert into stack59565292 values (1, 'VOLKAN');
insert into stack59565292 values (2, 'PIERRE');
commit;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stack59565292_typeA AS OBJECT
(        ID number(6),
       NAME varchar2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stack59565292_typeB AS OBJECT
( NAME varchar2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stack59565292_type_TABa AS TABLE OF stack59565292_typeA;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stack59565292_type_TABb AS TABLE OF stack59565292_typeB;
```

Then, below procedure works as you wish. Type constructors do the job. And you should define collection types in schema :  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00642_local_collection_types_not_allowed_in_sql_statement.htm

```
declare

  A stack59565292_type_TABa;
  B stack59565292_type_TABb;

begin
  -- Test statements here
  select stack59565292_typeA(x.ID, x.NAME)
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO A
    from stack59565292 x;

  FOR v_iterate IN A.FIRST .. A.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || A(v_iterate).ID || ' - NAME: ' || A(v_iterate).NAME);
  END LOOP;

  select stack59565292_typeB(x.NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO B from table(A) x;


  FOR v_iterate IN B.FIRST .. B.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('NAME: ' || B(v_iterate).NAME);
  END LOOP;

end;
```